# Is it compulsory to add Secure Flag to a Cookie over HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Till know my site is only HTTPS and I have added cookie.SecureFlag = true . I want to open it for HTTP as well so I'm forced to remove SecureFlag to a cookie as It is not working over it. Can you please tell me will my cookie sent through HTTPS (SSL) needs a secure Flag? Will it be secured without it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `secure` flag the cookie will only be sent to HTTPS endpoint. If you need to send the cookie to non-secure endpoints you should not use this flag although you should probably revise your design as it is considered bad practice to send authentication cookies over a non encrypted channel.

Bare in mind that it is not the `secure` flag that is actually securing anything inside the cookie. It is the SSL encryption which ensures that a man-in-the-middle will not be able to decrypt the value of the traffic. The secure flag only ensures that the browser will transmit the cookie over SSL.

Comment: To be more precise, the secure flag only ensures that the browser will **only** transmit the cookie over SSL.  Incidentally, it is also considered bad practice to send authentication cookies without setting the `HttpOnly` flag; setting `HttpOnly` to true makes the cookie inaccessible to javascript.